# How natural is the associativity law, or are there any real world non-associative examples

Tags: abstract-algebra

Are there any interpretations and applications of algebraic structures which are not associative?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octonion

Comment: nice, I am also looking for ''real world'' examples which could be given to a layman, like explaining commutativity by saying taking on clothes is non-commutative, but ordering a deck of cards is commutative because it does not matters in what order you perform your tasks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What about subtraction? We have $x-(y-z) \neq (x-y)-z$ when $z \neq 0$.

Example from real world ;-): You have 5 apples, and would like to give 3 of them to 3 friends. But 1 of them doesn't like it. So in the end you have $5-(3-1)=3$ apples, and not $(5-3)-1=1$.

Comment: And division, of course. $16/(4/2)\neq (16/4)/2$.

Comment: lmao the real world example is just too much!

Comment: roflcopter your nickname (SCNR)

Comment: Three diners have to pay a bill for a meal.  They pay ten dollars each, making $30$ dollars, but the cost was really only twenty-five dollars in total, so the waiter pockets two dollars and returns one to each diner. So the diners end up paying a net nine dollars each, making $27$, and the waiter now has $2$, making $29$, and the remaining dollar of the original $30$ has disappeared into non-associativity.

Answer (score 2):

The arithmetic mean $a*b=\frac{a+b}{2}$ is a *medial* operation: $(a*b)*(c*d)=(a*c)*(b*d)$. This property is used in psychophysics.

See J. Pfanzagl, Theory of Measurement, 2nd ed., Physica-Verlag, Wurzburg—Wien, 
1971, chapt.7.2 (Pfanzagl named such an operation *bisymmetric*).

Comment: do you remember what specifically is modelled with it in psychophysics, as I know psychophysics deals with the mapping of stimuli (real physical entities) to sensations (perceived ''quantity'' of stimulus), like air pressure to loudness, light waves to color and brightness, masses to ''heaviness'' and so on.

Comment: I wrote a reference in the question.

Comment: Not just the arithmetic mean. An [$f$-mean](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean#.C6.92-mean) has this property

Comment: @Henry Of course. And the geometric mean also.

Comment: @Boris - the geometric mean is an $f$-mean with $f(x)=\log(x)$

Comment: @Henry Yes, you are right. But I answered the question about applications.